# reading the result of LINQ query using Datarow

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How can I read the reult of LINQ query row by row .(Is it possible)?
I want to implemente this one but doesn't possible:

```
aspnetdbDataContext aspdb = new aspnetdbDataContext();
var res = from r in aspdb.RouteLinqs
          where r.UserId == userId
          select r;

foreach (DataRow row in res)
{
    // ...
```

An exception is thrown:

**Cannot convert type 'QuickRoutes.DAL.RouteLinq' to 'System.Data.DataRow'**

### **Edit:**

in the `foreach` block I have:

```
foreach (var row in res)
{
    var routeId = (int)row["RouteId"];
    var route = new Route(routeId)
                {
                    Name = (string)row["SourceName"],
                    Time = row["CreationTime"] is DBNull ? new DateTime() :
                                    Convert.ToDateTime(row["CreationTime"])
                };

    route.TrackPoints = GetTrackPointsForRoute(routeId);
    result.Add(route);
}
```

If I use var this error in some lines occure:

**Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'QuickRoutes.DAL.RouteLinq'**

Comment: That will read it row by row. The code inside the foreach loop iterates over the result

Comment: Just use the ``var`` keyword instead of ``DataRow``. I dont think the query yields an ``IEnumerable<DataRow>``, or does it?

Comment: what didn't work? any error message?

Comment: When you get an exception - it's a good idea to post the exception message in the question.

Comment: yes an erro:Cannot convert type 'QuickRoutes.DAL.RouteLinq' to 'System.Data.DataRow

Comment: What type is RouteLinqs? Is it a DataTable or a DataRow or something else ?

Comment: @HatSoft: If I had to guess: it is a Linq-to-SQL autogenerated class. The indicator for Linq-to-SQL is the ``...dbDataContext`` object.

Comment: Agree my bad should have noticed that before asking a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
foreach (RouteLinq row in res)
{
    // ...
```

or simply:

```
foreach (var row in res)
{
    // ...
```

Your Linq query doesnt return a collection of `DataRow` objects, but instead objects of a class that was autogenerated from your database table name.

**Edit, to account for the edit in your question:**

Why are you accessing the members of your objects like they are still `DataRow` objects?

You want to access it like:

```
int routeId = row.RouteId;
```

I really recommend you to look at a few basic Linq-to-SQL (or ORM in general) tutorials.

Comment: hey Philip,if I use **var** another error in my code occures:Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'QuickRoutes.DAL.RouteLinq

Comment: for example here: var routeId = (int)row["RouteId"];

Comment: What are you doing inside the ``foreach`` loop? Can you update your question with the code inside there? It seems you are trying to access some members like you do with a DataRow, like ``row[0]``, which of course will not work with your ``RouteLinq`` objects...

Comment: Just access the members of the ``RouteLinq`` objects directly, like ``row.RouteId``. That is what the ORM mapper does for you: it generates classes for each of your database tables, to enable convenient access to them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
foreach (var row in res)
{.....
```

**Update :** I would like to give you smaller syntax, hope you don't mind

```
foreach(var routeLinq in aspdb.RouteLinqs.Where(rl => rl.UserId == userId) )
{
    int routeId = routeLinq.RouteId;
}
```

Comment: How exactly is your answer different from mine?

Comment: If your reading the lines then it is not @PhilipDaubmeier you beat me on time

Comment: Oh, I see... Looks like we answered simultaneously :)